# How to construct expandable website structure?

Tags: asp.net

HI,

I have a ASP.NET webiste I created from craft and it now look a big mess. I want to reorganize this but don't know the good way to do it. Some first look well but later cause trouble with master page, image path...

Now I'm thinking of 2 ways:

- Using UrlWriter: but it seems lead to a bulk of path rewrite and usually lead to Resource not found or something
- Using a page as main entry and using Server.Tranfer to pull the right page content, despite of its location

Which is better? Do you have another method?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

There's another approach, `System.Web.Routing`, added in ASP.NET 3.5 SP1. Basically, you implement the [`IRouteHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.aspx) interface and manually route the request to an appropriate handler.

This is how ASP.NET MVC handles request routing. There's a [guide here that uses it for Web forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/05/14/using-asp-net-routing-independent-of-mvc.aspx).

By the way, consider looking at ASP.NET MVC and check if it's appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Moving to ASP.NET 3.5 requires a lot of changes and somehow MVC still not matured yet. I just want to restructure website but the problem of Master Page is hard to solve